# How to prevent CCleaner from wiping Start Menu frequently used applications list?

Tags: start-menu, ccleaner

Every time I use CCleaner to clean my system, regardless to what settings I set up (as far as I could find), it purges my Start Menu most used applications list (the main (lefrmost) column of the Start Menu). Is it possible to disable this behaviour? I only want it to delete temporary files.

Answer (score 2):

Just disable all `Windows Explorer` options specifically `Run(in Start Menu)` and `Start Menu Shortcuts` and `Desktop Shortcuts` and it should solve your problem.  You could also disable EVERYTHING except `Temporary Files` if you want and it would also solve your problem.